# Adding Order complicates Active Record Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an app where a customer can place an order to send items to a destination. The order needs to keep track of both the customer and the destination addresses.

I start with the following Active Record associations:

```
CUSTOMER
has_one :customer_address

CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
belongs_to :customer

DESTINATION
has_one :destination_address

DESTINATION_ADDRESS
belongs_to :destination
```

Now I want to add the concept of an Order.

So I make the following changes:

```
CUSTOMER
has_one :customer_address
has_many :orders

CUSTOMER_ADDRESS
belongs_to :customer

DESTINATION
has_one :destination_address

DESTINATION_ADDRESS
belongs_to :destination

ORDER
belongs_to :customer
has_one :customer_address, through: :customer
has_one :destination_address, through :destination
```

Two questions:

1. There is no symmetrical `belongs_to` for the two `has_one` associations in ORDER.  This seems wrong, but it also doesn't make sense conceptually for a customer or a destination to `belong_to` an ORDER, in part since there are many orders and only one address for a customer or destination.
2. What is the correct migration for ORDER?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The migration would look something like this:

```
class CreateOrder < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.string :name
      # add price, products etc.
      t.integer :destination_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You will also need a join table to link many `customers` to many `orders`. Something like this:

```
class CreateCustomerOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :customer_orders do |t|
      t.integer :customer_id
      t.integer :order_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```